# Повесить на 1 route 2 пути

Tags: reactjs

Может для кого-нибудь вопрос покажется слишком лёгким, но я ничего не нашёл :) 
У меня есть 2 **Route**, которые рендерят один и тот же **компонент**.

```
<Route path='/dialogs' render={() => <Dialogs data={props.data}/>}/>
<Route path='/letters' render={() => <Dialogs data={props.data}/>}/>
```

Можно их как-нибудь объединить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Переместите все свои роуты который должны монтировать один компонент в массив  и потом задайте этот массив как path к компоненту `Route`

```
const arr = ['/dialogs','/letters'];

<Route path={arr} render={() => <Dialogs data={props.data}/>}/>
```